# Присвоение класса при вводе значения в input

Tags: javascript, input, проверка

Есть конструкция:

```
<div class="prod">
   <input class="mquantity" name="mquantity[{$v->id}]" value="" type="text" data-price="{$v->price}"> 
</div>
```

Как сделать проверку input, чтобы при любом значении, кроме пустого, классу prod присваивался еще один класс nod?

Comment: А решение то на чем нужно? JS, jQuery или еще чего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JavaScript

Не силен в чистом javascript, и не уверен, что нет более лаконичного варианта, но как-то так (просто строго проверяем на неравенство пустой строке, при этом пробел тоже будет считаться символом):

```js
const input = document.getElementsByClassName('mquantity')

for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const thisInput = input[i],
    thisInputParent = thisInput.parentNode;
  
  if(thisInput.value !== '') thisInputParent.className += " nod";
  
  console.log(thisInputParent.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="prod">
   <input class="mquantity" name="mquantity[{$v->id}]" value="" type="text" data-price="{$v->price}"> 
</div>
<div class="prod">
   <input class="mquantity" name="mquantity[{$v->id}]" value="123" type="text" data-price="{$v->price}"> 
</div>
```

### jQuery

Тут я уже увереннее себя чувствую, по этому решение с проверкой на наличие любых символов кроме пробелов + динамическая обработка:

```js
const $input = $('.mquantity');
    
$input.each(inputOnKeypress);
$input.on('keyup keypress', inputOnKeypress);

function inputOnKeypress() {
  const $thisInput = $(this);

  $thisInput.closest('.prod').toggleClass('nod', $thisInput.val().match(/[^\s]/) !== null);
}
```

```css
.nod .mquantity {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod">
   <input class="mquantity" name="mquantity[{$v->id}]" value="" type="text" data-price="{$v->price}"> 
</div>
<div class="prod">
   <input class="mquantity" name="mquantity[{$v->id}]" value="123" type="text" data-price="{$v->price}"> 
</div>
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что знаете, что такое vanilla js на самом деле?

Comment: Всегда приравнивал к javascript (в моем представлении vanilla - что-то классическое xDD), но оказывается это то-ли библиотека то-ли фреймворк, как всегда не ясно. Поправил, что бы никому глаза не мозолило.

Comment: На самом деле, vanilla js - это просто шутка такая. Это и не библиотека, и не фреймворк

Comment: @Cheg, О_о "программистов шутка - редкая шутка". А, ну собственно получается я правильно предполагал что это такое, зачем вы так со мной, но теперь хотя бы знаю контекст употребления, говорим VanillJS - подразумеваем Ecmascript

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант на **jQuery:**

```js
$('#mquantity_input').bind('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == ' ') {
        $('#mquantity_div').removeClass('nod');
    } else {
        if ($('#mquantity_div').hasClass('prod') && !$('#mquantity_div').hasClass('nod')) {
            $('#mquantity_div').addClass('nod');
        }
    }
    $(this).next().html('class="' + $('#mquantity_div').attr('class') + '"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mquantity_div" class="prod">
   <input id="mquantity_input" class="mquantity" name="mquantity" value=""> 
   <span>class="prod"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Направление верное, но: 1) Если таких элементов несколько на странице, то id использовать неправильно; 2) Если использовать id для input ещё сработает, то для родителя уже нет (будет применять ко всем элементам с таким id); 3) Если уж проверять на пустоту строки и "не пробелы", то надо либо их обрезать пробелы и проверять остались ли символы, либо проверять по шаблону, так как могут и больше 1 пробела ввести; 4) Зачем проверка наличия класса .prod ? 5) Всю проверку (if ... else ...) по факту можно заменить на $('#mquantity_div').toggleClass('nod', $(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == ' ') )